# How to create nested connection in prisma query?

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm having issues getting the prisma/graphql-yoga client to work as I expect.

I'm trying to create mutation query that creates a connection between two nodes (`Game` and `User`), but the mutation is not behaving as I expect it to.

Here's the system I'm on:

```
node --version
v11.6.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.17.0",
    "prisma-client-lib": "^1.25.3"
  },
  ...
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.25
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

Here is the datamodel.prisma file:

```
type Game {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  board: String
  playerOne: User
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  wins: Int
}
```

Here is the mutation I send:

```
mutation {
  createGame(userId: "cjraz4ogb000s0894lbrugksi") {
    id
    board
    playerOne {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the resolver:

```
async function createGame(parent, args, context, info) {
  const game = await context.prisma.createGame({
    playerOne: { connect: { id: args.userId } },
    board: "[[]]"
  })
  return game
}
```

As you can see in the response, the resolver creates a `Game` object but there is no user associated with this game. Shown below is the response from the GraphQL playground mutation:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createGame": {
      "id": "cjraz8iwr001e08940ok9luki",
      "board": "[[]]",
      "playerOne": null
    }
  }
}
```

The response I expect would look something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createGame": {
      "id": "cjraz8iwr001e08940ok9luki",
      "board": "[[]]",
      "playerOne": {
        id: "cjraz8iwr001e08940ok9luki" <- id from above
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Solution

Just as @Errorname mentioned, I needed to implement the resolver function for the `playerOne` relation. Adding the lines of code below solved the issue.

```
function playerOne(parent, args, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.game({ id: parent.id }).playerOne()
}
```

Comment: Can you please share definition of mutation field from schema.graphql file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `prisma-client`, you must write the resolver for the connection ([Documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/03-build-graphql-servers-with-prisma-JAVASCRIPT-e001/#implement-resolver-functions)):

```
Game: {
  playerOne: (root, args, ctx) => ctx.prisma.game({id: root.id}).playerOne()
}
```